# calculate column sum for list in r

Tags: r

I have put all my files in a folder and use the following to read it

```
filenames <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")

all <- lapply(filenames, function(name) {
  readr:: read_csv(name)
})
```

I then extract the column names needed for further analysis

```
my_names <-  c("ID", "tt","dd")

new_list <-  lapply(all, "[", , my_names)
```

The list looks something like

```
$(tt=c(1,2,3), dd=c(4,7,9), ID=c("a","a","a"))
$(tt=c(5,5,10), dd=c(10,10,10),ID=c("b","b","b"))
```

I'm interested in calculating the sum of the column `tt` and `dd` and then save it in csv file. It should look like

```
tt  dd  ID
6   20  a
20  30  b
```

For a single data frame I can use sum(df$dd,na.rm = T) but how can I do it for a list? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just loop over the list:

```
tt = c()
dd = c()
ID = c()
for(i in 1:length(list)){
    tt=c(tt,sum(list[[i]]$tt))
    dd=c(dd,sum(list[[i]]$dd))
    ID=c(ID,sum(list[[i]]$ID))
}

sums = data.frame(tt,dd,ID)
```

But there might be a more elegant way in R.

Answer (score 1):

one option within the tidyverse (dplyr and purrr in this case) can be this:

```
library(tidyverse)


# dummy data
dd <- list(data.frame(tt=c(1,2,3), dd=c(4,7,9), ID=c("a","a","a")),
           data.frame(tt=c(5,5,10), dd=c(10,10,10),ID=c("b","b","b")))
# use map func
purrr::map(dd, ~ .x %>% 
  # group by the ID column
  dplyr::group_by(ID) %>% 
  # sum all numeric columns (you could just specify the columnnames aswell)
  dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum)))

[[1]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  ID       tt    dd
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         6    20

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  ID       tt    dd
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 b        20    30
```